# Encode/decode documents to base64 dynamically

Tags: python, shell

How do I encode pdf and word files in a folder to base64 and decode them and save into the same folder?
The pdf and word files are generated dynamically through a web service.

I would like to use python to do so.

I used this. But it gives the error
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "sample.py", line 7, in 
    base64.encode(open("hello.pdf"), open("hello1.b64", "w"))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\base64.py", line 496, in encode
    s = input.read(MAXBINSIZE)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 1340: character maps

```
base64.encode(open("hello.pdf"), open("hello1.b64", "w"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `base64` module, which is included in the standard lib.  The documentation is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html).

Comment: I used base64. But I am having issues using it. I have to encode pdf and word files

Comment: Open the files in binary mode: `open("file.pdf", "rb")` and  `"wb"`.